# AngularJS Выборка значений

Tags: angularjs

```
$http.get('/device/info/') 
.then(function(response) {
$scope.information = response.data;
});
```

`information` возвращает массив:

```
{name : "ivan", date: "07.12.2017", old : "23"}
```

Подскажите, как я могу разместить эти значения в индивидуальные scop'ы?
Что-то вроде:

```
$scope.name = response.data.name;
$scope.date= response.data.date;
$scope.old = response.data.old;
```

Или как вывести `information.name` без ng-repeat'ов и т.д.

Comment: `Object.assign($scope, response.data || {})`?

Comment: Уточните, что Вы хотели сказать. AngularJS пока для меня темный лес.

Comment: Неужели нет других вариантов?)

Comment: А чем не устраивает Ваш собственный вариант `$scope.name = response.data.name;` и т.д.?

Comment: Дело в том, что во вьюшке {{ name }} ничего не выводит. Потому и подумал, что ошибка в синтаксисе. А {{ information }} выводит вот что: {"name" : "ivan", "date": "07.12.2017", "old" : "23"}. Не понял почему колонки базы данных в кавычках!